# Talend; XML: Select one element of many based on its sub-element attribute

Tags: xml, extract, talend

I want to extract data from XML file with Talend

Except that one element contains many entries and I need only one specific entry

```
<Roles>
  <Party>
     <Code>Client</code>
     ... //other elements
  </Party>

  <Party>
     <Code>Sales</code>
     ...
  </Party>

  <Party>
     <Code>Third-party</code>
     ...
  </Party>
</Roles>
```

I want to extract only the entry Party where Code = Client, but when I map, I get all the entries extracted in the database.

How can I extract only the specific entry depending on the value of its sub-entry with Talend?

Answer (score 1):

There a a couple of options.

1. If you are not interested in the parties where code != client, then you can simply change your xpath loop in the Talend XML component. You need to loop through the parties where code == party. For example: //*[Code() = 'Client']
2. You can simply select all Parties and use a tMap to extract/do something with the Parties where element code == "Client". For more information about tMap, see this: https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataUserGuide520EN/5.2+tMap+operation (requires account though)

Answer (score 1):

create a job to read xml file then take a tFileInputXML component and configured as below.

1. loop Xpath query = `"/Roles/Party"`
2. then in mapping tab column= code, xPathQyery= "code"

once you configured like above then take tMap and connect main connection from tFileInputXML with appropriate schema.

now in tMap at right side, click on "Activate filter expression" and then map your "code" column in it, like below expression.

```
"Client".equalsIgnoreCase(row2.code)
```

hope this will solve your problem.